# how to compare two different date formats in oracle ? like in one table date store in 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' and another table 'dd,mm,yyyy'

Tags: oracle

how to compare two different date formats in oracle ? like in one table date store in 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' and another table 'dd,mm,yyyy'

Comment: Fix the data and store all the values using `date`.  That is why databases have built-in date formats.  Use them!

Comment: show us your table structure as DDL so we can see how you're storing your 'dates' - always use DATE to store dates

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions like "how to do this" without showing any effort are not usually welcome here.

Comment: See: [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand that you are storing date as string in your database column.
First convert the String to date datatype using the `to_date` function.
Use the function output for comparison.

Below is the sample usage of `to_date` function:

```
 SELECT TO_DATE ('2017/06/06 17:30:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') date1,
   TO_DATE ('01,05,2017', 'DD,MM,YYYY') date2
 FROM DUAL
```

**Note:** It is strongly recommended to store dates in columns having datatype `DATE` rather than storing them in `VARCHAR` columns. It will help to simplify the date operations.